# DeepLink - smart links (how to share and open it depending on device)

Tags: android, deep-linking

I couldn't find some simple solution for the problem I'm facing here.

**Setup**:

I have simple application on Android with integrated deep links. On the other side, client has web site (lets say www.test.com) with bunch or articles. All of the articles are also in the application. I'm using http scheme together with web url as a host.

```
<data android:scheme="http"
      android:host="www.test.com"
      android:pathPrefix="/articles" />
```

So basically, if the application is installed on the device - it will directly open link to the specific article.

**Request/Problem**:

I need to share articles from inside the application. Shared link: http://www.test.com/articles/1

- Shared link is opened on desktop browser - open article 1 in the browser (standard behaviour)
- Shared link is opened on mobile device:

  - user has application - open article 1 inside application
  - user has no application - open Google Play Store (to install application)

**Possible Solution 1**:

Use redirecting - some get parameter will be added to the link (http://www.test.com/articles/1?shared_link=true) If user has application it will open article inside it (default behaviour). For the other 2 cases - web needs to check what kind of device is in question (mobile or desktop) and in case it's mobile - redirect to Google Play Store.

The problem here is that I don't have an access to web. So implementing redirection is not really an option for me.

Is there any other way to setup this links? Thank you.